# Insert dynamically created div before content in a tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have the body of some HTML document as follows:

```
<body>
    <p>Here's some text</p>
</body>
```

Then the following appends the text to the `<body>`:

```
var jselem = document.createElement("div");
jselem.innerHTML = '<p>Some other text here</p>';
document.body.appendChild(jselem);
```

...resulting in:

```
Here's some text
Some other text here
```

Is there a way to generate the following after creating the `div` dynamically such that the following results?

```
Some other text here
Here's some text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking about DOM method [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).

```
document.body.insertBefore(jselem, document.body.firstChild);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MCnxM/